# Javascript/Google Apps Script: Create variables based on adjacent cell value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very, very new to Javascript/Google Apps Script, so thank you for your patience.

I am using a Google Sheet to organize data.

[image: Google Sheet example]

Is there a way to find a value in Column A, and then create a variable with the value of the cell to the right of it in Column B?

Example: If cell 6,1 says "Client Name", then variable clientNameInput is created from the value of cell 6,2 ? And then if later on for example I decide to move that whole row down 2 cells, so that "Client Name" is the value in cell 8,1, then the clientNameInput variable will now reflect the value of cell 8,2 ?

Currently, I am having to create variables for each value on each row, like so:

```
  const fourByFourInput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5,2).getValues();
  const clientNameInput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6,2).getValues();
  const clientDOBInput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(7,2).getValues();
```

Doing this allows me to then use the new variables, but I figured that if I move rows up or down on the Google Sheet in the future, then I will have to go back and re-write the cell values for each variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sample script 1:

About `for example I decide to move that whole row down 2 cells`, from your showing sample image, if the row values you want to retrieve are always the continuous 4 rows like "Client 4x4", "Client Name", "Client DOB", "Client Address" in order, how about checking the row number of 1st row of "Client 4x4"? When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

```js
function sample1() {
  const startValue = "Client 4x4"; // This is from your sample image.
  const numberOfValues = 4;

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(startValue).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext();
  if (!range) return;
  const [fourByFourInput, clientNameInput, clientDOBInput, clientAddressInput] = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2, numberOfValues).getValues();

  console.log({ fourByFourInput, clientNameInput, clientDOBInput, clientAddressInput }); // You can see the retrieved values in the log.
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, about `for example I decide to move that whole row down 2 cells`, if the rows of "Client 4x4", "Client Name", "Client DOB", "Client Address" are randomly changed, I thought that the following sample script might be able to be used.

```js
function sample2() {
  // This is from your question.
  const conversionObj = {
    "Client 4x4": "fourByFourInput",
    "Client Name": "clientNameInput",
    "Client DOB": "clientDOBInput",
    "Client Address": "clientAddressInput",
  };

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const obj = values.reduce((o, [a, b]) => {
    if (conversionObj[a]) {
      o[conversionObj[a]] = b;
    }
    return o;
  }, {});


  console.log(obj); // All values can be seen in the log.

  // For example, when you want to retrieve the value of "clientNameInput", please use the following sample.
  console.log(obj.clientNameInput);

  // If you want to use the values as each variable, you can use the following script.
  const {fourByFourInput, clientNameInput, clientDOBInput, clientAddressInput} = obj;
}
```

Comment: Tanaike, you genius! It works perfectly. I'm using sample script 2 because I want to be able to re-organize the rows if needed. Thank you so much!!